# How do I create celery queues on runtime so that tasks sent to that queue gets picked up by workers?

Tags: django, queue, celery, amqp, worker

I'm using django 1.4, celery 3.0, rabbitmq

To describe the problem, I have many content networks in a system and I want a queue for processing tasks related to each of these network.

However content is created on the fly when the system is live and therefore I need to create queues on the fly and have existing workers start picking up on them.

I've tried scheduling tasks in the following way (where content is a django model instance):

```py
queue_name = 'content.{}'.format(content.pk)
# E.g. queue_name = content.0c3a92a4-3472-47b8-8258-2d6c8a71e3ba
add_content.apply_async(args=[content], queue=queue_name)
```

This create a queue with name `content.0c3a92a4-3472-47b8-8258-2d6c8a71e3ba`, creates a new exchange with name `content.0c3a92a4-3472-47b8-8258-2d6c8a71e3ba` and routing key `content.0c3a92a4-3472-47b8-8258-2d6c8a71e3ba` and sends a task to that queue.

**However I never see the workers picking up on these tasks.** Workers that I have currently set up are not listening to any specific queues (not initialized with queue names) and pick up tasks sent to the default queue just fine. My Celery settings are:

```py
BROKER_URL = "amqp://test:password@localhost:5672/vhost"
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False

from kombu import Exchange, Queue

CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = 'default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'direct'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'default'

CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue(CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE, Exchange(CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE),
        routing_key=CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY),
)

CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = True
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
```

Any idea how I can get the workers to pick up on tasks sent to this newly created queue?

Comment: Why not just use one queue and pass the `content.pk` along as a parameter? What is the added benefit to creating a new queue?

Comment: Possible added benefits are: ability to spin up dedicated workers if necessary for a content network that is receiving heavy traffic. Also for statistical and log encapsulation etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell the workers to start consuming the new queues. Relevant docs are [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#queues).

From the command line:

```
$ celery control add_consumer content.0c3a92a4-3472-47b8-8258-2d6c8a71e3ba
```

Or from within python:

```
>>> app.control.add_consumer('content.0c3a92a4-3472-47b8-8258-2d6c8a71e3ba', reply=True)
```

Both forms accept a destination argument, so you can tell individual workers only about the new queues if required.

Comment: Though as @EWit suggested, I would stick with the default queue mechanism unless you have a strong reason to partition jobs to different workers. The add_consumer call isn't 'sticky' - if you restart a worker you will have to re-apply the queue subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks Gavin. I'm checking out the add_consumer method right now. Will let you know if I can get it working.

Comment: Great this worked! Thanks a lot Gavin. Re-creating queues are not a problem since they are always created on the fly if necessary.

Comment: You're welcome tarequeh. I just want to emphasise from my previous comment that if you restart a worker (e.g. when there is a code change or server restart) it will start off only consuming the default queue. You will have to do add_consumer each time a worker is started.

Answer (score 4):

We can dynamically add queues and attach workers to them.

```
from celery import current_app as app
from task import celeryconfig #your celeryconfig module
```

To dynamically define and route task into a queue

```
from task import process_data
process_data.apply_async(args,kwargs={}, queue='queue-name')
reply = app.control.add_consumer('queue_name', destination = ('your-worker-name',), reply = True)
```

You have to keep the queue names in persistent data store like redis so you can remember it when it restarts.

```
redis.sadd('CELERY_QUEUES','queue_name')
```

celeryconfig.py also uses the same to keep remember queue names

```
CELERY_QUEUES = {
    'celery-1': {
        'binding_key': 'celery-1'
    },
    'gateway-1': {
        'binding_key': 'gateway-1'
    },
    'gateway-2': {
        'binding_key': 'gateway-2'
    }
}
for queue in redis.smembers('CELERY_QUEUES'):
        CELERY_QUEUES[queue] = dict(binding_key=queue)
```