# Create celery multiple queues

Tags: python, celery

I've a configuration file which contains a category list

```
cat_link = {'cat1':[link1,link2....],'cat2':[link3,link4....],'cat3':[link5,link6....],'cat4':[link7,link8....]}
```

I want to create queues as per the total number of categories defined in configuration file, also when I process the links for a particular category , each queue should process its own set of links.

The task for processing the links is same. I just want is that every category links should be processed in their specific queue.

It should be something like this:-

```
for category, link in cat_link.iteritems():
    process_link.apply_async(args=[link],
                             queue=category,)
```

**How should I create dynamic queues, keeping in mind that any category can be removed/added in future?**

**How should I my celeryconfig look like? Currently it is as below :-**

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://'

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json']
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Oslo'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True

#Should I read my `cat_link` config setting in a loop and then create the queues??
```

**I've seen different queues for different tasks, but is it possible different queues for same task?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want different queue dynamically,

```
process_link.apply_async(args=[link1],
                         queue=queue1)

process_link.apply_async(args=[link2],
                         queue=queue2)
```

Also you have to insert following in configuration file

```
CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = True
```

But one thing you have to care about is when starting worker, you have to pass -Q 'queue name' as argument

For ex

```
celery -A proj worker -l info -Q queue1,queue2
```

for consuming from that queue 'queuename'

Comment: Thanks @latheef for a quick response. However, on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687997/how-do-i-create-celery-queues-on-runtime-so-that-tasks-sent-to-that-queue-gets-p , I've seen the user using `from kombu import Exchange, Queue`. Is it of any importance ? I didnt understood.

Comment: Celery uses default queue named 'celery'.Now this link says about setting CELERY_QUEUES without dynamic creation.Also telling worker to start consume from new queue, if worker already started.

Comment: How do I run celery in daemon with newly created queues.??

Comment: you can use `supervisor` for daemonizing this worker.

Comment: I need add a job dynamically,  one job contain a lot of tasks. All tasks are same .How can I make different jobs have diferent queue name, and just one worker process all the queues?  In programmatically.

Comment: If I have to pass queue name as a command line argument then I don't think it is a dynamic behaviour

Comment: is there any solution to this yet?